# Tkinter window changing size becuase items in listbox

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter, window

**Hello!**

Im developing a GUI to simple python script I made (The GUI developed using SpecTcl).
The script is searching a website and show the search results in a list box.

The code is:

```
results = search(query) #return a list of results, or False if there are no results
msg = msgMngr()
if results == False:
    msg.onWarn("No results", "No search results to " + query) #Warn the user that there are no results
else: 
    self.list.delete(0, END) #clear listbox
    for item in results: #enter all items to the listbox
        self.list.insert(END, item)
```

To demonstrate the problem, i made a simple program which add to the list "hello world!" every time the user click the button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsA1K.png

but, when there are more items than the list size capacity, its just get bigger: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WvG2.png

It also happneds horizontally if the item is too long: i.imgur.com/a88DRxy.png

**What I want to do is:** the window will always stay in his original size, and there will be 2 scrollbars if there are too many items or the item length is too high.

I tried just adding scrollbars but it didnt help.
I also tried forcing the screen size using `root.resizable(0,0)`, and it still got bigger and bigger.

It's my first question here, if i did something wrong/didnt described the problem well just tell me and ill fix :)

Thanks!

Comment: I use `ScrolledText` for scrolling textboxes. If you want to use your current frame, you may have to add scrollbars to a canvas and then attach your current root frame to that canvas. You can find more info on scrollbars here: http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-autoscrollbar.htm

Comment: After you add the scrollbars, the scrollbars are adjusted to appear and disappear based on the initial size of the canvas. When you start adding content to the listbox, you will have to update the canvas scrollable region. If you need help coding that, I have some examples for that.

Comment: `ScrolledText`, is the simplest solution for this :)

Comment: What you report is not standard behavior. Normally the widget will not grow. You must have some code that is making that happen. Can you show us a small, complete program that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Lib/idlelib/ScrolledList.py might help you.  If you use it, copy the file as the undocumented files within idlelib are private to Idle and subject to change.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Thanks it helped me, but i need 2 scrollbars as Bryan Oakley did in his answer

Comment: @BryanOakley I tried what you did, but for some reason I couldnt done that... But when i copied your code it worked great! If you could take a look at my code it would help me a lot :) thanks anyway (code: pastebin.com/apep3ayg (main) & pastebin.com/5CJ2ccHa (user interface) [There are 2 files becuase this is how SpecTcl works...])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is not the default behavior of a tk listbox widget. Here is an example showing a listbox with scrollbars:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, borderwidth=1, relief="sunken")
        b = tk.Button(self, text="search", command=self.add_one)

        self.lb = tk.Listbox(self, borderwidth=0)
        self.lb.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.lb.yview)
        hsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self.lb.xview)
        self.lb.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set, xscrollcommand=hsb.set)

        b.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
        vsb.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="ns")
        self.lb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        hsb.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="ew")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def add_one(self):
        self.lb.insert("end", "hello world!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```